# Backup Un-Bootable Windows 7 Partition with Ubuntu Live CD, then restore partition to fresh Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, backup, restore

My Windows 7 computer can not get past the Windows 7 Splash Screen, cannot enter safe mode (stops loading at \Windows\system32\DRIVERS\cbvd.sys), cannot be system restored (from restore point), and cannot be repaired from the Windows 7 CD (never gets passed the "Searching for Installations screen).  I've tried everything I can think of to get this computer to boot, but am now resorting to creating a backup image through a Windows Ubuntu Live CD.  As a side note, if anyone knows how to fix the problem itself I'd really appreciate it.

I have two 500gb hard drives raided together to create a 1tb hard drive on the laptop, so I can't take the hard drives out and extract them to another Windows computer.  I do not want to just copy my most-needed files to an external hard drive because I have programs with misplaced install CDs on this computer, so I'm resorting to a complete backup and restore.

I think that's all the before-hand information you'd need.  So what I'd like to do is use Ubuntu Live CD (or any other program if it'd work better), to access my raided hard drives.  I'd then like to backup this 1tb to an external hard drive.  I will reinstall Windows on my laptop, then restore the files from the external hard drive to the fresh install.

My problem is that I can not find a program compatible to both Windows 7 and Ubuntu that will allow me to back up from Ubuntu then restore from windows 7.  If anyone knows of a program that can do what I'm hoping for, or how to fix my computer, or another method entirely, I'd REALLY appreciate it.

Thanks, 
Christian

Comment: What happens at the splash screen, locks up or just sits there? How long did you let it set at the splash screen? What did you do/install (if anything) before the startup problem?

Answer (score 1):

Can you see the RAID in your Ubuntu live CD? If you can, boot up with Ubuntu and install ddrescue with the following: `apt-get install ddrescue`

Use ddrescue to copy your disks to an external 1TB disk. This disk should be readable by another Windows machine.

If ubuntu cannot see your RAID, you would have to try another rescue live CD such as RIP or systemrescue, however the procedure should be the same.

Here's the [ddrescue manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/manual/ddrescue_manual.html) for reference.